# Save image file to IBM Bluemix Node.js application

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I have a Node.js application on IBM Bluemix.

I need to let the user upload a image. In my localhost, the image is save into the folder, no problems...

But when I do the same in production, the file isn't save to the server corresponding folder...

Someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a Cloud Foundry app ... the file system is ephemeral, you need to save the images somewhere external to the app for them to be persisted through app restarts.

There is a sample app that shows how to do this using Cloudant - https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/nodejs-cloudant

Comment: So, I should use a service like cloudinary.com, and save into my app db (mongoDB) only the link to the cloudinary?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the directory using `__dirname` , but every time you redeploy your application you will lose the files. Stoping and Restarting should be ok.